# Identifying Semiconductor Fabrication Defects

Tags: manufacturing

During my semiconductor fabrication lab, I encountered defects in my devices. Can you help me identify the technical name for these defects?

The first defect is caused by particle contamination and looks like similar to this:

[image: Defect due to particle contamination]

While the second is caused by underdeveloped photoresists (I believe):

[image: Defect due to underdeveloped photoresists]